# Allowlist URL pattern (HTTP) Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to add an allowed URLs to my Dynamic Links. It works with links to the app store/google play. I have a staging and production server and I need to set the ofl parameter accordingly. The production URL is HTTPS and works. But the staging URL does not work It is HTTP and has "-", I'm not sure if those are any relevant and the cause of the problem but those are the only differences.

For example: `http://gettingstartedapp-env.bx7dx222kw.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/`

Using this example, I'm listing bellow things I've tried so far:

```
^http://gettingstartedapp\-env\.bx7dx222kw\.us\-east\-2\.elasticbeanstalk\.com/.*$

^http://gettingstartedapp-env\.bx7dx222kw\.us-east-2\.elasticbeanstalk\.com/.*$

^.*gettingstartedapp-env\.bx7dx222kw\.us-east-2\.elasticbeanstalk\.com/.*$

^http://.*.com/.*$
```

I still get URL is disallowed. What can it be?